# How do I rotate the page and have two figures side-by-side?

Tags: graphics, floats, rotating

I would like to dedicate a whole page to two figures, which I wish to place side by side in the horizontal layout.

What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

This is what I have already tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{minipage}{\textheight}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5]{image1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5]{image1}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{minipage}
\end{turn}

\end{document}
```

However, I am getting error messages which unfortunately I don't understand.

Comment: Welcome! Please don't shout as it gives people headaches. Note, too, that you are likely to get more out of answers if you put more into your question. A small, compilable document demonstrating the issue you want help with makes it much more likely that answers will apply to your particular situation in ways which genuinely solve the problem.

Comment: To the down-voter: please don't down-vote without leaving a comment explaining how the question can be improved. Especially in the case of a new user and a question posted less than 5 minutes ago! Indeed, isn't down-voting at all rather premature at this point?

Comment: "However, I am getting error messages which unfortunately I don't understand." -- Consider posting these. It may improve your chance of getting an error. Even if I did know which LaTeX error messages you understand and which ones you don't, I wouldn't be able to figure out which error message you received unless you only didn't understand one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You like to have landscape oriented figure? Something like following figure?
[image]

It is obtained with following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \usepackage{rotating}% for sidewaysfigure

    \begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\hsize}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-a}
\caption{Sub figure A}
    \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
%\hfill <-- it is superfluous 
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\hsize}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-b}
\caption{Sub figure B}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure in landscape orientation}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
    \end{document}
```

Cause of errors in your MWE is missing width of subfigures, correct syntax is `\begin{subfigure}{<width>}` and probably missing package `rotating`, which beside `sideways` (figure, table) also define macros `rotatebox`, `turn`, etc. For details see package documentation.

**Edit:**
One errors was caused by use of `float` environment inside of (non-float) `minipage` (what is forbidden), as pointed Gonzalo Medina in his comment.

Comment: Another error in the original code: the OP was using `figure` inside a `minipage`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes, I overlooked this (since this was the first what I was erased in OP MWE :-) )

Comment: Since the two `subfigure` environments each occupy `0.5\textwidth`, the `\hfill` directive doesn't do much. I'd delete that line and simply place an `%` (comment symbol) immediately after the first `\end{subfigure}` instruction.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for your remark. I correct my MWE.

Comment: Do you know how I can do exactly this, but without sub-figures? I want them to be numbered just Figure 1 and Figure 2, not Figure 1 a and Figure 1 b. Thank you

Comment: Let suppose that I know, but why you should not use sub-figure? BTW, if you like to get a solution for this, please ask a question in which you show, what exactly is your problem and what you tray so far.

Answer (score 2):

While the errors have been pointed out by Zarko, here is another option using `pdflscape`.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \usepackage{pdflscape}% for landscape

    \begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}%[htb]
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\hsize}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-a}
\caption{Sub figure A}
    \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\hsize}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-b}
\caption{Sub figure B}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure in landscape orientation}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: I have bad eyes. :) corrected.

Comment: Do you know how I can do exactly this, but without sub-figures? I want them to be numbered just Figure 1 and Figure 2, not Figure 1 a and Figure 1 b. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The errors have been pointed out by Zarko, but answers show only another appproaches, although turn 90 degrees a minipage with the subfigures is also a valid idea that should work.

This is the minimal (now really working) example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textwidth][c]{\textheight}
\begin{subfigure}[h]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subcaption}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[h]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{A subcaption}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{The main caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Or, if you want the shorter code of the `subfigure` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textwidth][c]{\textheight}
\subfigure[A subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfigure[B subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{The main caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```